# Yii Rights set sub menu visible false based on Role

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, rights

I am new to Yii Framework.  In my application iam used Rights using this link : http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/423/installing-yii-users-and-rights-to-newly-created-yii-app/

I want to make navigation bar submenu item visible based on user's role in yii rights.

my navigation sub menu item looks like this :

```
array(
    'label'=>'Low Inventory Level <span class="caret"></span>',
    'url'=>'#',
    'itemOptions'=>array('class'=>'dropdown','tabindex'=>"-1"),
    'linkOptions'=>array('class'=>'dropdown-oggle','data-toggle'=>"dropdown"),
    'items'=>array(
        array('label'=>'RM Warehouse', 'url'=>array('/rmlInventoryMwh/load')),
        array('label'=>'Prod Warehouse', 'url'=>array('/rmlInventoryPwh/load ')),
    ),
    'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('master'),
)
```

Comment: Can you state what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add checkAccess to your sub menu:

```
    array(
    'label'=>'Low Inventory Level <span class="caret"></span>',
    'url'=>'#',
    'itemOptions'=>array('class'=>'dropdown','tabindex'=>"-1"),
    'linkOptions'=>array('class'=>'dropdown-oggle','data-toggle'=>"dropdown"),
    'items'=>array(
        array('label'=>'RM Warehouse', 'url'=>array('/rmlInventoryMwh/load'),'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('sub_menu')),
        array('label'=>'Prod Warehouse', 'url'=>array('/rmlInventoryPwh/load '),'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('sub_menu')),
    ),
    'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('master'),
)
```

And then just add permissions to your operation for user roles.

Comment: Thanks, but i have a one clarification  what is Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('sub_menu')) and how to set access for 'sub_menu'

Comment: Make new operation - "sub_menu" in your rights interface, then go to permissions and assign roles which have access to that operation. It's all in your `/rights` interface.